# Installing beamer.cls when using rocker/verse and shiny

Tags: r, docker, shiny, dockerfile, beamer

I'm new to Docker and am a user of TeX.

I'm using a Dockerfile

```
FROM shrektan/shiny

MAINTAINER Steven

RUN R -e "install.packages(c('shiny', 'googleAuthR', 'dplyr', 'googleAnalyticsR', 'knitr', 'rmarkdown', 'jsonlite', 'scales', 'ggplot2', 'reshape2', 'Cairo'), repos = 'https://cran.rstudio.com/')"

COPY app /srv/shiny-server/

EXPOSE 3838
```

to run a shiny app that allows users to run/download a `beamer_presentation` `.pdf` report.

With the Dockerfile above, the app runs well, all functionality exists, but I get an error suggesting that `beamer.cls` is not installed (I have included only the pertinent parts):

```
[...]
processing file: GA_report.Rmd
`geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
`geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
`geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
`geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x' 
output file: GA_report.knit.md

tlmgr search --file --global '/beamer.cls'
tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2017 < 2018)
Cross release updates are only supported with
update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
Please see https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
Warning: running command ''tlmgr' search --file --global '/beamer.cls'' had 
status 1
! LaTeX Error: File `beamer.cls' not found.

! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

Warning: Error in : Failed to compile /tmp/RtmpmiHjqW/file185881070c.tex. See 
file185881070c.log for more info.
[No stack trace available]
```

**I'm lost in trying to identify how to install the `beamer.cls` to this docker image.**

The docker file above is made up of the image [built from this Dockerfile](https://github.com/shrektan/shiny/blob/shrek/Dockerfile) which in turn is built from the [rocker/verse Dockerfile here](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker-versioned/blob/master/verse/3.5.1/Dockerfile).

At the top of the [`rocker/verse` Dockerfile](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker-versioned/blob/master/verse/3.5.1/Dockerfile), the author clearly states that they're using a "dummy" version of TexLive and suggests that [FAQ 8 here](https://yihui.name/tinytex/faq/) provides more information. The FAQ link provides examples of how to install packages but not install a class, i.e., `beamer.cls`.

Although I'm new to Docker, I'm at a loss as to how I should go about installing the `beamer.cls` to my Docker image. I feel like there's something remarkably useful in the error log I provided, but can someone point out what I'm missing?

Comment: Have you tried adding `RUN tlmgr install beamer` to your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: I have not. Can that command be anywhere in the Dockerfile?

Comment: Yes, though I would put it next to the other `RUN`.

Comment: Adding that line to my Dockerfile produced [this error.](https://i.imgur.com/lyPG5Yt.png) However, after more research, I added a line from [this question on tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429714/tlmgr-remote-repository-is-newer-than-local-2017-2018). However, now I get [a new tex error, shown in ths gist](https://gist.github.com/stevenranney/2b2405148233fc815ceba88a2fa1dd96). [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404218/is-there-a-problem-with-beamer-in-the-latest-miktex-update) suggests that this issue may be fixable, but I'm unsure.

Comment: Using `RUN tlmgr install beamer translator` should install both beamer.cls and translator.sty. The issue with TL 2017 vs. TL 2018 is annoying. The shrektan/shiny image hasn't been rebuild for 4 months and therefore still uses R 3.4.4 and TL2017. The underlying rocker/verse is meanwhile at R 3.5.1 and TL2018. You could ask the image maintainer for an update, or build it yourself.

Comment: Ah-HA! Thanks. I'm two days old to Docker and am learning as I'm going. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RalfStubner I'd be happy to accept your previous comment as an answer if you want to make it such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle it should be enough to add

```
RUN tlmgr install beamer translator
```

to your `Dockerfile`. Unfortunately this does not work directly, since the `shrektan/shiny` image has not been updated for several month and is still using TexLive 2017 (and R 3.4.4). The underlying `rocker/verse` iamge is meanwhile using TL 2018 and R 3.5.1. While it is possible to  [workaround](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429714/tlmgr-remote-repository-is-newer-than-local-2017-2018) the "TL to old" issue, I suggest to either ask the maintainer for a rebuild of `shrektan/shiny`, rebuild it yourself or include the necessary parts in your own `Dockerfile` based on `rocker/verse`.

Comment: I ended up using your second suggestion, building from `rocker/verse` and adding the bits and pieces where necessary. New to Docker last week, with help from SO and the rocker repos, I've been able to climb the steep learning curve. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I’m the author of shrektan/shiny. The docker image has been archived and no longer being maintained. The image doesn’t include the LaTeX engine and it probably be the reason of your problems.

Anyway, you may try rocker/verse or my new image shrektan/rdocker4shinyserver (similar to rocker/verse but with more packages pre-installed. Github https://github.com/shrektan/rdocker)

This image includes the Tinytex which should fix your problem).

Comment: Thanks for putting shrektan/shiny together. It served as a great learning tool for me. I did start using `rocker/[img]` as my base.